# React Native upload image to AWS Server not working for Android

Tags: javascript, android, image, amazon-web-services, react-native

I was having some problem when trying to upload image from React Native to AWS Server. Here is my code:

```
async function uploadImageAsync(uri) {
  console.log(uri);
  let apiUrl = '...' 
  let uriParts = uri.split('.');
  let fileType = uri[uri.length - 1];
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', {
    uri,
    name: `image.jpg`,
    filename: `image.jpg`,
  });

  let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  };

  return fetch(apiUrl, options);
}
```

The results that printed out at the console are:

```
file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540gh%252Ftp2/ImagePicker/37c89140-2172-4566-98a2-e7393ea72e89.jpg
Object {
  "uploadResponse": undefined,
}
Object {
  "uploadResult": undefined,
}
Object {
  "e": [TypeError: Network request failed],
}
```

What I did is I pick an image from image picker, then I will upload it to AWS server. If success, print out success message. If failed, print out those in the console above.

The strange thing is, it managed to upload on iOS but not Android. Any ideas why is it so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. I was trying to upload images from the phone's camera roll or photo gallery to AWS S3. It was working fine for IOS, but was throwing error **TypeError: Network request failed** for Android device.

So, I used npm library [rn-fetch-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob), instead of fetch() method.

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';

RNFetchBlob.fetch('PUT', AWSPresignedURL, {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}, Platform.OS === 'ios' ? RNFetchBlob.wrap(filePath) : `RNFetchBlob-${filePath}`)
```

**Please note, in my case, I had different file paths for IOS and Android devices. We handle it in different ways using rn-fetch-blob**

Sample filePath variable data for

1. IOS device -

"/Users/Niveditha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B41EB910-F22B-4236-8286-E6BA3EA75C70/data/Containers/Data/Application/B88777C6-6B10-4095-AB67-BB11E045C1DE/tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/img.jpg"

2. Android device -

"**file://**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.uploadcameraroll/files/Pictures/img.jpg"

**Code to generate AWSPreSignedURL -**

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
let S3 = new AWS.S3();

AWS.config.region = 'ap-south-1'; 
AWS.config.accessKeyId = 'AKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; 
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = 'XIJyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX+H+GR';

S3.getSignedUrl( 'putObject' , 
        { Bucket: 'upload-app-photos',
          Key: 'upload/' + fileName,
          Expires: 120,
          ACL: 'public-read'
         }, (err,url) => {
            if (err) {
               console.log("error ", err);
               return;
           }
            console.log("AWSPreSignedURL ", url);
      })
```

This issue was officially raised -  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25244

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you are trying to upload files to AWS S3 service but if you are, you can look into AWS Amplify React Native which may help you a lot.

By using this library, you can upload files by:

```
Storage.put('test.txt', 'Hello')
    .then (result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Details are at https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I have encountered this problem. You want to use 'fetch' to upload file(the type is mutipartfile),  but it always show [TypeError: Network request failed]. You can reference this issue(https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551). Have a try if you are using RN0.62.

Here is the summary from the github user [**abumostafa**] in the linked issue.

Whoever is still struggling with this issue. it's happening because of Flipper network plugin.
I disabled it and things work just fine.

My workaround to make this work is commenting out line number 43

```
38      NetworkFlipperPlugin networkFlipperPlugin = new NetworkFlipperPlugin();
39      NetworkingModule.setCustomClientBuilder(
40          new NetworkingModule.CustomClientBuilder() {
41            @Override
42            public void apply(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
43      //        builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
44            }
45          });
46      client.addPlugin(networkFlipperPlugin);
```

in this file `android/app/src/debug/java/com/maxyride/app/drivers/ReactNativeFlipper.java`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and finally solved it. So I think I can give you a hint.

1. First, [TypeError: Network request failed] means the problem is on the client side.
2. apiUrl should https://...

   you can simply test this with localtunnel npm. it gives you https format url that proxies to your local url.

2. you can add type: 'image/jpeg' to form data.

   you can check [media type](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Media_type#/Type_image) here

This is part of fetching code

https://gist.github.com/zeroFruit/d46d4cae57e5e8cf59e1b541c0bf322e

Comment: the apiUrl is in the specified format. Just that I removed it as this is a school project. Also, where do I put in 'type: 'image/jpeg''?

Comment: on the .append('image', { ..., type: 'image/jpeg' }) side

Comment: Yeap I tried it but it does not solve the problem. Could it be the internet permission problem?

Comment: I don't know is this related internet permission problem.. :( I linked part of fetching code. I hope it could help you..

Comment: But it was working 100% on iOS and 0% on Android. So I actually have no idea on what's wrong here.