# Cannot upload images captured from camera using react-native-image-crop-picker

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-image-crop-picker for images,,,i can display and upload images taken from gallery by same plugin using same code....whereas i can display the images captured from camera using same plugin...but cannot upload them to server.

the error i get is

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (C:\Repos\247client\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16)
    at settle (C:\Repos\247client\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (C:\Repos\247client\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:77)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (C:\Repos\247client\node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (C:\Repos\247client\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:572)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (C:\Repos\247client\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:394)
    at C:\Repos\247client\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:507
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (C:\Repos\247client\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:190)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (C:\Repos\247client\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:349)
    at C:\Repos\247client\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:106
```

my image information is:

```
{uri: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/b9e9acdd-5807-43c8-9c6b-08af4f9e37ce.jpg", width: 3456, height: 4608, mime: "image/jpeg", size: 247313}
height: 4608
mime: "image/jpeg"
size: 247313
uri: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/b9e9acdd-5807-43c8-9c6b-08af4f9e37ce.jpg"
width: 3456
```

i am using same upload code for both i.e uploading images taken from galery and camera.

the code is

```js
export const uploadPrescription = async (
  id,
  address,
  contact_no,
  textPrescription,
  data
) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("user_id", id);
  formData.append("contact_no", contact_no);
  formData.append("medicine_description", textPrescription);
  formData.append("location", address);
  var i = 0;
  data.forEach(photo => {
    formData.append(`prescriptions[${i}]`, data[i]);
    i++;
  });
  console.log(formData);

  return (await makeRequest(urls.uploadByPrescription, "POST", formData)).data;

};

export const makeRequest = async (url, method, data) => {
  console.log("i am here");
  const headers = await getHeaders();
  console.log(headers);
  let response = await axios({
    method,
    url,
    data,
    headers: headers,
    timeout: url.includes("register") ? 30000 : 10000
  });
  console.log(response);
  var data = await response;
  return data;
};
```

Comment: Is the captured image from the gallery?

Comment: the captured image is from camera....For image from gallery there is no issue

Comment: having the exact same issue on my app, on android only. iOS works fine. did you manage to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Please refer to the answer given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62087375/6508545**

I had used [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-crop-picker) npm package to get images from Camera Roll and Photo Gallery. And then upload it to **AWS S3 Server**.

I could upload it easily from IOS devices but not from Android.

The issue was URI or file path for images fetched in android and IOS devices were different.

Sample filePath variable data for

1. IOS device -

*"/Users/Niveditha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B41EB910-F22B-4236-8286-E6BA3EA75C70/data/Containers/Data/Application/B88777C6-6B10-4095-AB67-BB11E045C1DE/tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/img.jpg"*

2. Android device -

*"**file://**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.uploadcameraroll/files/Pictures/img.jpg"*

Answer (score 0):

@Niveditha Gowda

If you are using FormData on android for uploading image to server, you should check filename fro FormData returned, because Android has no filename so that the server can not response your request.

in my code, I have to use "modificationDate" for filename

```
formData.append('avatar', {
  //   uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? path : path.replace('file://', ''),
  uri: path,
  type: mime,
  name: Platform.OS === 'android' ? `${modificationDate}.jpg` : filename,
});
```